# Configure padrino logger for stage environment?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

How can I enable padrino logger of other environment other than prod, dev or test. Like, for example, stage env?

My padrino app on my stage env do not write at file log.

I tried

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:stage][:stream] = :to_file
Padrino::Logger::Config[:stage][:log_level]  = :devel
```

but I received the error

```
$ - > RACK_ENV=homolog bundle exec padrino start
Users/carlospereira/ws/nutri/config/boot.rb:15:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/bundler/gems/padrino-framework-94d09af7573a/padrino-core/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:24:in `require'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/bundler/gems/padrino-framework-94d09af7573a/padrino-core/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:24:in `start'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/bundler/gems/padrino-framework-94d09af7573a/padrino-core/bin/padrino:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/bin/padrino:23:in `load'
from /Users/carlospereira/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@nutri/bin/padrino:23:in `<main>'
```

In my boot.rb I have:

```
PADRINO_ENV  = ENV["PADRINO_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development"  unless defined?(PADRINO_ENV)
PADRINO_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__) unless defined?(PADRINO_ROOT)

require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)  
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default, PADRINO_ENV)

Padrino::Logger::Config[:homolog][:stream] = :to_file
Padrino::Logger::Config[:homolog][:log_level]  = :devel

Padrino.before_load do
  Encoding.default_internal = nil
end

Padrino.after_load do
  DataMapper.finalize
end

Padrino.load!
```

I cut the comments, but line 15 is

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:homolog][:stream] = :to_file
```

I also tried

```
if PADRINO_ENV == 'homolog'
  log_file_name = "#{PADRINO_ROOT}/log/#{PADRINO_ENV}_#{(ENV['APP_PROCESS_NAME'] || File.basename($0))}.log"
  log_file = File.new(log_file_name, "a+")
  PADRINO_LOGGER = { :homolog    => { :log_level => :debug, :stream => log_file }} 
end
```

but I still get the message:

```
/Users/carlospereira/ws/nutri/config/boot.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant PADRINO_LOGGER
No logging configuration for :homolog found, falling back to :production
```

line 19 is

```
PADRINO_LOGGER = { :homolog    => { :log_level => :debug, :stream => log_file }}
```

And no log is written on logfile.

Any ideas?

Tkz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how we enabled it in our staging environment.

The relevant portion of `config/boot.rb`

```
PADRINO_LOGGER = { :staging => { :log_level => :debug, :stream => :to_file }} if PADRINO_ENV == 'staging'
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathan! I did as you say and when I start app in my stage env (homolog) I get an error `/Users/carlospereira/ws/nutri/config/boot.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant PADRINO_LOGGER
No logging configuration for :homolog found, falling back to :production` and still don't write to log file. I will update my question with that

Comment: That error sounds pretty straight forward, you already have `PADRINO_LOGGER` defined somewhere else... What does your earlier definition look like?

Comment: Ha...  Of course! I put the code after `bundle.require(:default, PADRINO_ENV)` and get the error. Now I put in the begin of the file after `PADRINO_ROOT` definition and works!
Thanks a lot, Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

You could set this in `config/boot.rb`

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:stage][:stream] = :to_file
Padrino::Logger::Config[:stage][:log_level]  = :devel
```

Refer to [API Doc](http://www.padrinorb.com/api/Padrino/Logger.html)

Comment: Hi, Ck-. Thank you for your attention, but I tried this before, and I get: 

`/config/boot.rb:21:in block in <top (required)>': undefined method []=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: I can't guess why you get that error unless you post `boot.rb` file and the error stacktrace.

Comment: I updated my post with my boot.rb and the stacktrace. 
Am I missing something? maybe I should declare my :homolog env somewhere else?
Thank you again, Ck-

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a hash otherwise i would get ascii colours in the log:

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:development] = { :log_level => :debug, :stream => :to_file }
```